# Is it possible to convert projects wizard created for MSVS 2005 to MSVS 2008 format automatically

Tags: visual-studio, templates, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, data-conversion

I have a bunch of wizards created for MSVS 2005. Is it possible to convert them to MSVS 2008 format automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at these posts:

- [How to use solutions and projects between Visual Studio 2005 and 2008](http://blogs.msdn.com/djpark/archive/2007/11/07/how-to-use-solutions-and-projects-between-visual-studio-2005-and-2008.aspx)
- [Running VS2008 & VS 2005 side by side - project file difference](http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeffrey.palermo/archive/2007/11/27/running-vs2008-amp-vs-2005-side-by-side-project-file-difference.aspx)

You will only need to change a few lines if you do it manually. So i guess this is trivial if you automate it.